# Google map for Business

Tags: android, google-maps, layout

How to move to google map for Business in android , I do all steps in the Google developer Documentation .
https://developers.google.com/maps/premium/android-get-started
except the step of getting purchased google Api key .

I have purchased Client Id , how to use it to have functionality .
when i do those steps my debug key stop .

If anyone has this experience, please let me know how to setup Google Static Maps API V2 for business on Android.
thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here are the steps how to setup Google Static Maps API V2 for Business on Android:

- Go to the Google Cloud Console. https://cloud.google.com/console/
- Select your project.
- In the sidebar on the left, select APIs & auth. Then select Credentials.
- Create a new client id for OAuth 2.0.
- Choose Installed appilcation & Android.
- Use new client id in your application.

You may use the Official Google Documentation for Google Static Maps API as your reference: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/static-maps/

Comment: I have Client ID , but where to place it in my project to view the map .

Comment: and how to use it to get activated map key